# Nodejs Mysql null value inserted on database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
app.post('', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('connected as id' + connection.threadID)
        const params = req.body
        var name = params.name
        var tagline = params.tagline
        var description = params.description
        var image = params.image

        connection.query('INSERT INTO beers (name, tagline, description, image) VALUES (name,tagline,description,image)',
            (err, rows) => {
                connection.release()

                if (!err) {
                    res.send('Successfully added record of name' + params.name)
                } else {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })

        console.log(req.body)
    })
})
```

Comment: You don't have any placeholders (`?`) for parameters in your query and you don't add any parameter values to your query. How do you think `values (name, tagline ...)` will magically pick up your variables?

Answer (score 1):

As @derpirscher suggested, you should add the parameter values to the query.

Try to change your code like this:

```
    const { name, tagline, description, image } = req.body.params; 
    connection.query(
      'INSERT INTO beers (name, tagline, description, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [name, tagline, description, image],
      (err, rows) => {
        connection.release();

        if (!err) {
          res.send('Successfully added record of name' + params.name);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
```